# displaying an attachment in a data view webpart

Tags: data-view-web-part

Guys how can I display an image attached to a list item in a data view web part.  I cant find any examples of this on the net

Answer (score 1):

This post here http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2590041 explains how to get over an issue when creating Custom display forms which need to show attachments.

You would notice the presence of a certain field

```
<SharePoint:FormField runat="server" id="AttachmentsField" ControlMode="Display" FieldName="Attachments" __designer:bind=""/>
```

Follow similar steps to include it in your data form.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using XSL?

```
<xsl:element name="SharePoint:AttachmentsField">
  <xsl:attribute name="runat">server</xsl:attribute>
  <xsl:attribute name="FieldName">Attachments</xsl:attribute>
  <xsl:attribute name="ControlMode">Display</xsl:attribute>
  <xsl:attribute name="Visible">true</xsl:attribute>
  <xsl:attribute name="ItemId">
    <xsl:value-of select="@ID"/>
  </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:element>
```

Comment: This code change the title of the page to ["Name" column value]

Answer (score 0):

Please refer :http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31895/Displaying-Attachments-with-the-Data-View-Web-Part, it has same functionality implemented.

Comment: Please dont just link to external content, as they tend to die fast. Paste in the relevant content and then link.